# metpy.calc.dewpoint_from_relative_humidity w/ GFS data : ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (31,) (34,)

Tags: python-xarray, metpy

I'm trying to do metpy.plots.SkewT() from GFS data.

When I try to calculate Td (from T, rh), the pressure levels don't match up.

Is there some clever way (w/ xarray ?) to slice and dice so they line up ?

The following code plots the temperature on a skew-t, but when the metpy.calc.dewpoint_from_relative_humidity is uncommented, it complains : ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (31,) (34,)

Any tips on making the code better are welcome as well ....

```
import xarray
xds0 = xarray.open_dataset(f'https://thredds.ucar.edu/thredds/dodsC/'
    'grib/NCEP/GFS/Global_onedeg/Best')

subset0 = {'method' : 'nearest'}
subset0['lon'] = 238. ; subset0['lat'] = 38.

import metpy.plots
xda1 = xds0.metpy.parse_cf('Temperature_isobaric')
import datetime
vtname0 = xda1.metpy.time.name # eg : time1
subset0[vtname0] = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

T = xda1.metpy.sel(**subset0).values * metpy.units.units(xda1.units) #.squeeze()

vname0 = xda1.metpy.vertical.name # isobaric6 = 0..33
p = xda1[vname0].values * metpy.units.units(xda1[vname0].units)

skewt1 = metpy.plots.SkewT()
skewt1.plot(p, T, 'r')

xda1 = xds0.metpy.parse_cf('Relative_humidity_isobaric') # isobaric = 0..30
rh = xda1.metpy.sel(**subset0).values #* metpy.units.units(xda1.units) #.squeeze()
#Td = metpy.calc.dewpoint_from_relative_humidity(T, rh) # ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (31,) (34,) 
#skewt1.plot(p, Td, 'g')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This process can get a little cleaner by making use of MetPy's [XArray accessor](https://unidata.github.io/MetPy/latest/tutorials/xarray_tutorial.html) to simplify selection based on generic dimensions like 'time' and 'vertical'. We can also get the values on common levels formed using [`np.intersect1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html):

```
import datetime
import metpy
import numpy as np
import xarray

xds0 = xarray.open_dataset('https://thredds.ucar.edu/thredds/dodsC/grib/NCEP/GFS/Global_onedeg/Best')
temp_da = xds0.metpy.parse_cf('Temperature_isobaric')
rh_da = xds0.metpy.parse_cf('Relative_humidity_isobaric')

# Formulate subset
subset0 = {'method' : 'nearest',
           'lon': 238.,
           'lat': 38.,
           # Can use 'vertical' here if we pass to metpy's version of sel
           # Use the array of values for pressure that are present in both
           'vertical': np.intersect1d(temp_da.metpy.vertical, rh_da.metpy.vertical),
           'time': datetime.datetime.utcnow()}

temp = temp_da.metpy.sel(**subset0)
rh = rh_da.metpy.sel(**subset0)

# Need to rename the coordinate on RH to match that of temperature
rh = rh.rename({rh_da.metpy.vertical.name: temp_da.metpy.vertical.name})

# Get vertical coordinate (pressure) as a unitted array
p = temp.metpy.vertical.metpy.unit_array

# Calculate dewpoint
td = metpy.calc.dewpoint_from_relative_humidity(temp, rh)

# Plot on SkewT
skewt1 = metpy.plots.SkewT()

# For some reason matplotlib doesn't like the temp array with units inside
# a DataArray
skewt1.plot(p, temp.metpy.unit_array, 'r')
skewt1.plot(p, td, 'g')
```

The code above requires MetPy 1.0 for its native support of XArray `DataArray`s. For earlier versions, the call to `dewpoint_from_relative_humidity` should instead be:

```
td = metpy.calc.dewpoint_from_relative_humidity(temp.metpy.unit_array,
                                                rh.metpy.unit_array)
```